# Running a node on one computer with a link to another computer running the ROS master

Tags: raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm curious if anyone has attempted to run a ROS node on one computer, and have it pass messages through some form of link to another computer that runs the master. Pretty much what the ROS arduino packages do, but with a computer in place of the raspberry pi.

I've only dabbled in ROS so forgive me if this is a question with an obvious answer.

Having just got a neat little SPI screen for my raspberry pi 2, i'm keen to play with some ROS stuff with it, but as i'm sure you're all aware, getting ROS to run Raspbian is an absolute nightmare. I can't use the screen with Arm Ubuntu since as though it requires a custom kernel.

Food for thought.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215088/running-a-node-on-one-computer-with-a-link-to-another-computer-running-the-ros-master/) by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-08-02**:
I have used laptops and there process seemed easier.

**Comment by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on 2015-08-02**:
Helpful.
Yes, i invested in several x64 based single board computers to run full linux to avoid installing ROS on the Pi work wise, this is a curiosity.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-08-02**:
well Ben, hopefully someone will be able to help you this since I am using Asus laptop on my turtlebots.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If by *some form of link* you mean ethernet and TCP/IP, then yes (any other transport could also work, but would require (much) more work). This would simply be a matter of setting the `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` / `ROS_IP` variables correctly. See [ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) for more info.

Also, be sure to have a working network before attempting to do anything more than simple tests (diagnosing network issues can become quite complex if you're running a full application). See [ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and make sure all tests pass and return valid results.

An alternative to a single master would be to run a multi-master setup. This is much more involved though, and if all your CPUs are on the same physical network, not wireless and connected by reliable links, a single master setup probably makes more sense. In any case, see [wiki/sig/Multimaster](http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Multimaster), [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) (just one example) and [rocon](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon) (robotics in concert) for a start.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1